# Working with serial port under Linux (Multi-I/O Controller)

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have the Linux Mint 18.1 x64 and the PCI 9835 Multi-I/O Controller.
I use /dev/ttyS4 and /dev/ttyS5 ports for exchanging with my device (only one port at one time). When I use /dev/ttyS5 all is right.

But when I use /dev/ttyS4 I get a strange behaviour. Sometimes, the ports change after reboot. At first. Some port options from port to port are different! Why? At second. When I use write() I get the error 5 (Input/output error) very often (almost all time).

Further, I have known, that a behavior of my program depends on a DCD line state. If I do not connect any cable or if I connect a part cable (not full), my program works fine. If I connect the full cable, I see errors! But if I connect the DCD line at the end of the cable to GND or V-, my program also works fine.

When I tested my program I had disconnected the cable from my device.
CuteCom and minicom work fine. See my program bellow. It is the simplified test code. I have two controllers. Both have the same behaviour. What is wrong?

Why do stty return with error sometimes?
I cut off error processing from my code to be more readable. But it there is :)

```
uname -a
Linux intel 4.4.0-71-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 24 12:59:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dmesg | grep tty
[   11.726824] 0000:02:02.0: ttyS4 at I/O 0xe050 (irq = 18, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   11.747864] 0000:02:02.0: ttyS5 at I/O 0xe040 (irq = 18, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A


lspci -v
02:02.0 Communication controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCI 9835 Multi-I/O Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic 1P2S
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e040 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e030 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e020 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e010 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: parport_serial
    Kernel modules: parport_serial

stty -g -F /dev/ttyS4
0:0:14b2:0:3:1c:7f:15:1:0:1:0:11:13:1a:0:12:f:17:16:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

stty -g -F /dev/ttyS5
500:5:cbd:8a3b:3:1c:7f:15:4:0:1:0:11:13:1a:0:12:f:17:16:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

stty -a -F /dev/ttyS4
speed 115200 baud;stty: /dev/ttyS4: Input/output error

stty -a -F /dev/ttyS4
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^A; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt -echoctl -echoke -flusho -extproc

stty -a -F /dev/ttyS5
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

---

```
...
struct termios options;

fd = open(comName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

tcgetattr(fd, &options)

cfsetispeed(&options, speed);
cfsetospeed(&options, speed);

options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
options.c_cc[VMIN] = 60;

options.c_cflag |= CREAD;
options.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;

options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
options.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;

options.c_lflag = 0;
options.c_oflag = 0;

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
...
```

Comment: Why are you showing us the *stty* output in "stty-readable form" (i.e. the `-g` switch) instead of "human-readable form" (i.e. the `-a` switch)?  *"my program works fine"*, *"See my program bellow. It is the simplified test code."* -- All I see is some initialization code with no testing of the return codes.  In theory that code should always "work" (i.e. there's no way for it to fail).

Comment: I am sorry, I edited my message. Old output is only for quick comparing. And I have an error checking.